# Axes toolbar is not shown when axes is re-parented

Tags: matlab, tabs, matlab-figure, toolbar, parent

In MATLAB R2019a (Update 2), when using the following code, the axes toolbar is not shown when selecting Tab2 or Tab3.

```
classdef test < handle
    properties
        Ax
    end
    methods
        function self = test()
            f = figure;
            tg = uitabgroup(f, 'SelectionChangedFcn', @self.onSelectionChanged);
            t1 = uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab1');
            uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab2');
            uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab3');
            self.Ax = axes(t1);
        end

        function onSelectionChanged(self, ~, e)
            self.Ax.Parent = e.NewValue;

        end
    end
end
```

I would like to know how to make the toolbar appear in the selected tab.

**Edit:** The following code shows the problem better: The axes toolbar is stucked in the first panel, while the axes is in second panel. However, to reproduce this, don't copy and paste into your MATLAB command window. It only happens if the axes' parent changes after the axes toolbar is drawn. Thus I split the code into two sections:

```
f = figure;
p1 = uipanel(f, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0 0 .5 1]);
p2 = uipanel(f, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [.5 0 .5 1]);
ax = axes(p1);
```

And now change the axes' parent:

```
ax.Parent = p2;
```

Here is the result:[image: Result after re-parenting the axes]

And here is what I expect:

[image: expected result]

So far, I haven't figured out how to trigger the event that puts the toolbar in the correct position.

Neither changing the `Visible` property of the `figure`, `axes`, `axtoolbar` or `uipanel` helped. Also, overriding the toolbar by a new one does not help.

Comment: The `toolbar` is a child of the `figure`, not the `axes`.

Comment: @Hoki: The toolbar's `Parent` property points to the `axes` and the `figure`'s `Children` property only contains the `tabgroup`. Furthermore, the toolbar does not have something like a `Position` property...

Comment: @Hoki: Maybe you mixed it up. I'm talking about the relatively new axes toolbar as generated by `axtoolbar`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. [This blog post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-graphics-interactivity) might be relevant.

Comment: You should add that the toolbar is "stuck" on the first tab/panel where it appears. If you switch tabs/panels before showing it, it'll be (only) in the new position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I considered the behaviour described above a bug, I have filed it to Matlab staff.

They responded to get around this issue, one shoud re-set the Parent of the axes toolbar. In case of the test class from above:

```
function onSelectionChanged(self, ~, e)
    self.Ax.Parent = e.NewValue;
    set(self.Ax.Toolbar,'Parent',[],'Parent',self.Ax);
end
```

Comment: Having this in mind, another solution is to include the axes in a `uipanel` (which is good practice anyway) and re-parent that panel.

Comment: Your comment could be a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have some bad news and some good news: based on my attempts it appears that one cannot move the same toolbar between containers (tabs or panels) due to a MATLAB restriction, however, a workaround is possible. Below is the details of how I reached this conclusion.

---

Upon investigating this a bit, I noticed that several properties of the `AxesToolbar` change after it is shown for the first time, two of them caught my eye - `HasTrueParent` and `NodeParent`.

Aha. So the toolbar now has a parent, which means that somewhere in the hierarchy of children, the tab should see the toolbar. Let's investigate further:

I've added another property to your class called, `Tabs`, and this is how I populate it in the constructor:

```matlab
      self.Tabs(1) = uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab1');
      self.Tabs(2) = uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab2');
      self.Tabs(3) = uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab3');
      self.Tabs = handle(self.Tabs);
```

Then, setting after setting (and hitting) a breakpoint we can see that:

```matlab
K>> allchild(self.Tabs(1))
ans = 
  2×1 graphics array:

  AnnotationPane
  Axes
K>> allchild(self.Tabs(2))
ans = 
  0×0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.
```

Notice that `AnnotationPane`? This is the layer that contains annotation and probably also the toolbar. How can we know for sure? We can set its `Visibility` to `'off'`, and the toolbar stops appearing.

So naturally, one might be tempted to change the `Parent` of that pane, but this results in the error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.shape.internal.AnnotationPane/setParentImpl
Cannot change parent of AnnotationPane object.
```

---

So what can be done about this? If you create new axes in every new tab,

```matlab
hFig = figure();
hTG = uitabgroup(hFig);
for iTab = 1 : 3
    hTab = uitab(hTG, 'title', "Tab" + iTab);
    hPanel = uipanel(hTab);
    hAxes(iTab) = axes(hPanel);
end
```

their toolbars will be created correctly. From there, it's a matter of relocating the children (of the axes) and updating the limits/viewport.

Comment: The problem with your workaround is the number of axes that are created. As the [blog post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-graphics-interactivity)(you mentioned above) shows, this can lead to performance problems. The blog post was the reason why I want to re-parent the `axes`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer from my previous comment:

Another solution is to put the axes in a `uipanel` (which is good practice anyway) and then re-parent the panel:

```
classdef test < handle
    properties
        Ax
    end
    methods
        function self = test()
            f = figure;
            tg = uitabgroup(f, 'SelectionChangedFcn', @self.onSelectionChanged);
            t1 = uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab1');
            uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab2');
            uitab(tg, 'Title', 'tab3');
            self.Ax = axes(uipanel(t1)); % uipanel as axes parent
        end

        function onSelectionChanged(self, ~, e)
            self.Ax.Parent.Parent = e.NewValue; % re-parent the uipanel

        end
    end
end
```